# Powershell .split and append while keeping split format

Tags: string, powershell, split

Hello my question is how do i keep the format for a string that has had the .split run on it. What i want

```
$test="a.b.c.d.e"
$test2="abc"
#split test
#append split to test2
#desired output
abc
a
b
c
d
e
```

I know if i perform split on a string such as

```
$test="a.b.c.d.e"
$splittest=$test.split(".")
$splittest
#output
a
b
c
d
e
```

However when i try to make it so that i want to append the above split to a string

```
$test2="abc"
$test2+$splittest
#output
abca b c d e
```

while

```
$splittest+$abc
#output
a
b
c
d
e
abc
```

Is there a way to append the split string to another string while keeping this split format or will i have to foreach loop through the split string and append it to the $test2 string one by one.

```
foreach ($line in $splittest)
{
$test2="$($test2)`n$(splittest)"
}
```

I would prefer not to use the foreach method as it seems to slow down a script i am working on which requires text to be split and appended over 500k times on the small end.

Comment: `$splittest+$abc` produces an array, `$abc+$splittest` produces a string - which are you interested in?

Comment: i want a string

Comment: `@($test2;$splittest) -join [Environment]::NewLine` or `$OFS = [Environment]::NewLine;$test2+$splittest`

Comment: Thank you this is working and keeping everything as a string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're seeing is the effect of how PowerShell's operator overload resolution.

When PowerShell sees `+`, it needs to decide whether `+` means sum (`1 + 1 = 2`), concatenate (`1 + 1 = "11"`), or add (`1 + 1 = [1,1]`) in the given context.

It does so by looking at the *type* of the left hand side argument, and attempts to convert the right hand side argument to a type that the chosen operator overload expects.

When you use `+` in the order you need, the string value is to the left, and so it results in a string concatenation operation.

There are multiple ways of prepending the string to the existing array:

```
# Convert scalar to array before +
$newarray = @($abc) + $splittest

# Flatten items inside an array subexpression
$newarray = @($abc;$splittest)
```

Now all you have to do is join the strings by a newline:

```
$newarray -join [System.Environment]::NewLine
```

Or you can change the output field separator (`$OFS`) to a newline and have it joined implicitly:

```
$OFS = [System.Environment]::NewLine
"$newarray"
```

Finally, you could pipe the array to `Out-String`, but that will add a trailing newline to the entire string:

```
@($abc;$splittest) |Out-String
```